# Node and Twilio integration

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have written a programmable SMS feature using Twilio in nodejs. I have a message that has options to select and when user sends back any response I want to send an automated response using twilio.

I have completed all except after processing the response from user my automated response is not being delivered to user.

[image]

I keep getting above thing from my twilio dashboard.

Here is my response handler code..

```
 app.post('/ui/sms',function(req, res) {
    //req.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/xml';
    //req.headers['Accept'] = 'text/xml';
    try {
        console.log('Processing Response', req.headers);
        const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
        const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
        const fromTwilio = isFromTwilio(req);
        console.log('isFromTwilio: ', fromTwilio);
        if (fromTwilio) {
            let msg = req.body.Body||'';
            if (msg.indexOf('1')>-1) {
                twiml.message('Thanks for confirming your appointment.');
            } else if (msg.indexOf('2')>-1) {
                twiml.message('Please call 408-xxx-xxxx to reschedule.');
            } else if (msg.indexOf('3')>-1) {
                twiml.message('We will call you to follow up.');
            } else {
                twiml.message(
                    'Unknown option, please call 408-xxx-xxxx to talk with us.'
                );
            }
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
            res.end(twiml.toString());
        }
        else {
            // we don't expect these
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Cannot process your request.' });
        }
        /*processSMSResponse(req, function(response) {
            res.json(response);
        });*/
    } catch(e) {
        res.json(e);
    }
});


function isFromTwilio(req) {
console.log('REQ HEADER:::::::::\n', req);
// Get twilio-node from twilio.com/docs/libraries/node
const client = require('twilio');

// Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
const authToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// The Twilio request URL
//const url = 'https://mycompany.com/myapp.php?foo=1&bar=2';
const url = 'https://xxxx.com/ui/sms';
var reqUrl = 'https://xxxx.com/ui/sms'
// The post variables in Twilio's request
//const params = {
    //CallSid: 'CA1234567890ABCDE',
    //Caller: '+14158675310',
    //Digits: '1234',
    //From: '+14158675310',
    //To: '+18005551212',
//};
const params = req.body;
console.log('post params: ', params);

// The X-Twilio-Signature header attached to the request
try{
    Object.keys(params).sort().forEach(function(key) {
        reqUrl = reqUrl + key + params[key];
    });

    var twilioSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', authToken).update(Buffer.from(reqUrl, 'utf-8')).digest('base64');
    //const twilioSignature = req.header('HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE');
    console.log('twilioSignature: ', twilioSignature);
} catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
return client.validateRequest(
                authToken, 
                twilioSignature, 
                url, 
                params
            );
}
```

I have explicitly tried setting headers but no use. I'm clue less on what twilio expects from me or how to modify headers.

```
{
 "status": "Error",
 "error": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Response><Message>Please call 408-xxx-xxxx to reschedule.</Message></Response>"
}
```

I see this as body in Twilio console and it has the response that I need but could not send as a message..

Comment: your content type is wrong, https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/12300

Comment: try setting content type using res.set() method and statuscode with res.statusCode() and res.send() to send body. res.end() is not correct method to send response back.

Comment: tried it no use..

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

From looking at your code and trying it myself I can't see anything generally wrong with it. There are two potential failing points here though:

1) I can't see your `isFromTwilio` function. If that one fails it might cause an error and then return JSON instead of XML on your error handler. I don't know why it would reply with the TwiML in that JSON though.

2) The other behavior I could reproduce (except that the TwiML is not being sent in the response body) is when I don't include `body-parser` in the middleware chain. This will cause `req.body` to be undefined and therefore `req.body.Body` will throw an error that is then being caught and JSON is being returned.

Do you have `body-parser` included and properly included as a middleware? You can either do it this way:

```
const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false });
```

or if you only want to use it for this one endpoint you can add `urlencoded({ extended: false })` as an argument before your request handler:

```
app.post('/ui/sms', urlencoded({ extended: false }), function(req, res) {
```

I hope this helps.

Cheers,

Dominik

Comment: Yes I have it in my server.js file but urlencoded({ extended: false }) set to true as default.

Comment: I added the extra function it returns true if the X-Twilio-Signature is valid.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. There seems to be clearly some error thrown. I would suggest to either directly attach a debugger to it using Chrome or VS Code or alternatively first to swap out your own `isFromTwilio` function with our built-in Express middleware: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/lib/webhooks/webhooks.js#L63